# UIButton not render exactly as XIB's contentVerticalAlignment value

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

I want to button 's top is align to the button's titleLabel's top , so I set the content vertical alignment to top in xib . this is works well in xib , but after build , the titleLabel seems still layout with center vertical alignment . What did I miss?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a comment: What you see in Storyboard / Interface Builder:

- is not always ***exactly*** what UIKit renders in the Simulator
- which is not always ***exactly*** what UIKit renders on a Device

This is why we test, test, test... on different simulators and devices.

---

So, what's going on here?

UIKit uses the frame of the button's `.titleLabel` to determine the button's intrinsic size.

For a default button, with no explicit width or height set, UIKit insets the title label by `6-pts` on the Top and Bottom.

Here are 2 buttons - both with no Height constraint. **Button 1** is the default Content Alignment of center/center, **Button 2** is set to Left/Top. The button title label background is cyan, so we can easily see its frame.

Storyboard / IB:

[image]

Runtime:

[image]

Debug View Hierarchy (note the label frame vs the button frame):

[image]

So, with an 18-pt system font, the title label height is `21.0` ... add `6-pts` top and bottom and the button frame height is `33-pts`.

It doesn't matter whether you set the Control Alignment to Top / Center / Bottom or Fill ... UIKit still takes the label height and adds `6-pts` Top and Bottom "padding."

What to do to get actual Top alignment? Let's look at a couple approaches.

Here are 6 buttons in a stack view:

[image]

**Button 1** is at the default center/center, with no Height constraint.

**Button 2** as we've seen, has Control Alignment Left / Top ... but has no effect on the vertical alignment.

**Button 3** is also Left/Top, but let's give it an explicit Height (we'll use  `80` to make things obvious). Looks better - but there is still `6-pts` of "padding" added to the top of the title label.

Now, you may have seen this at the top of the Size Inspector panel:

[image]

This looks promising! Let's set the Title Insets **Top** to Zero!

Whoops -- it's already Zero?!?!?!?

Same thing with the Content Insets!

Turns out, if the the edge insets are at the default, the padding is added anyway.

We *could* try setting the Title Inset Top to `-6` and, because labels center the text vertically, we'll also have to set the Bottom inset to `6`. This works... but we may not want to rely on that value of `6` to be accurate in future iOS versions.

**Button 4** - lets try `Content Insets -> Bottom: 1` ... and it looks like we're on our way! The label is now top-aligned with the button frame!

So...

**Button 5** - remove the `Height: 80` constraint so we can use the default button height. D'oh! The button frame height is now title-label-height plus zero-top plus one-bottom...

**Button 6** - finally, we'll use `Content Insets -> Bottom: 1` with an explicit Height constraint of `33` (the default button height).

---

So... what if we don't want to set an explicit Height? Perhaps we're going to change the title label's font size later? Or we run into some other issue?

You could use a custom `UIButton` subclass.

Here's an example, marked as `@IBDesignable` so we can see its layout in Storyboard / IB:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyTopLeftAlignedButton: UIButton {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        self.contentVerticalAlignment = .top
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
        // if we want to see the title label frame
        //titleLabel?.backgroundColor = .cyan
    }
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            if let v = titleLabel {
                var t = titleEdgeInsets
                let h = (bounds.height - v.frame.height) * 0.5
                t.top = -h
                t.bottom = h
                titleEdgeInsets = t
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit** - *response to comment...*

If your goal is to match the "Button 5" style - where the button height matches the title label height - best bet is probably...

Select the button, then in the Size Inspector panel use these settings:

[image]

The `0.1` Top and Bottom values will override the default `6-pt` Top/Bottom "padding," reducing it to effectively Zero.

Comment: A so  wonderful explanation , thanks a lot for you work @DonMag, In fact what I want is the button 5 style , How do you find the way that set Content Insets -> Bottom: 1 to do this work:)

Comment: @ximmyxiao - see the **Edit** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: So you get this method by one to one test? I used to think that  you got a secret guide from apple developer or somewhere else?:) @DonMag